# Calling a function after a download request is finished

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

I'm currently trying to get execute this call back function after the request is finished, so I'm able to close the modal where

```
function handleDownloadFinished(): void{
setDownloadingActivity(false);}
```

I want this code to run after this:

```
public static async exportData(id: number, _callback: Function): Promise<void> {
const queryString = stringifyQuery(
  {
    token: BaseAPI.getJwt(),
  },
  {
    arrayFormat: "bracket",
  }
);
const anchorElement = document.createElement("a");
anchorElement.download = "file.xlsx";
anchorElement.href = `URL`;
anchorElement.click();
_callback();}
```

Unfortunately, It runs both functions at the same time, and then the animation does not run. Some times, I'm able to make the animation run, but not stop. Right now, to have It working, the application relies on user input to stop it running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser does not communicate the progress of downloaded files to a webpage in any way. So you code *cannot* know when a download has finished.

You're just going to have to design your UI with this fact in mind.

Comment: So, changing the exportData function to work with Axios, for exemple, would give me the ability to have that progress?

Comment: Sort of. If you wanted to load an external resource into your webpage, for use on tht webpage, you could monitor that that with simple promises. But you cannot download a file to someone's computer from a webpage with axios.